# Laravel 5.1 Reusable Slug

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.1

Hello how can I make the unique slug logic reusable in my project. I have a method for creating a unique slug in my Product model and I want to use that same logic in my other model here:

```
/**
     * Set the name attribute and automatically the slug
     *
     * @param string $name
     */
    public function setNameAttribute($name)
    {
        $this->attributes['name'] = $name;

        if(! $this->exists)
        {
            $this->setUniqueSlug($name, '');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Recursive routine to set a unique slug
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @param mixed $extra
     */
    public function setUniqueSlug($name, $extra)
    {
        $slug = str_slug($name . '-' . $extra);

        if (static::whereSlug($slug)->exists())
        {
            $this->setUniqueSlug($name, $extra + 1);

            return;
        }

        $this->attributes['slug'] = $slug;
    }
```

Comment: Re-usable logic: create a trait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Martin Beans comments would be the best way to go about this.

There is nothing wrong with Paul Vidal's way, however, I wouldn't use the Base Model approach unless you're going to use it with every model.

As long as you're not using different field names for the slug and you're using something like a parent slug (i.e. product/{slug}) you should be able to put the above code straight into a trait and then `use` in on the models you want to.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, you can create a Base model class that extends from eloquent, and then extends the rest of your models from that base model. Create the method "setUniqueSlug" in that base model to be accesible from any other.
Or you can create a Helper class, so you can call "setUniqueSlug" from anywhere.